# Importing the graph kit in React Native results in error 500

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I am using the latest version of Expo. I have created a project by `expo init my_project` and added the [React Native Chart Kit](https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit).
Here is the package.json:

```
    {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

When I import the following it gives me the error: "The development server returned response error code: 500":

```
  import {
  LineChart,
  BarChart,
  PieChart,
  ProgressChart,
  ContributionGraph,
  StackedBarChart
} from "react-native-chart-kit";
```

Why this error happens even though this module is accessible through the Expo as it stated in this [page][2]?

[2]: https://forums.expo.io/t/any-graph-library/1674/7[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most cases this error is related to your `node_modules`, try the following:

1. Stop your Expo application server
2. Delete your `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json`
3. Run `npm install` or `yarn install`
4. Run `npm install --save react-native-svg`
5. Start your application by running `expo start -c`

Hope this helps!

Comment: It still gives me the same error. Is there a problem with my workflow? I use blank (from managed workflows).

Comment: please try running `npm install --save react-native-svg` then start your application again with `expo start -c`

Comment: glad that did the trick, i updated the answer to include it in the solution. cheers!

Answer (score 4):

To use `react-native-chart-kit`, you also have to install `react-native-svg`. So, just install it through `npm` and hopefully it will work.

```sh
$ npm i react-native-svg react-native-chart-kit
```

You can try my project on this repo: [click here](https://github.com/LintangWisesa/ReactNative_ChartKit). 
Enjoy