# error 500 when I importing any package from Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm  using expo. When I imported any packages from expo SDK in  [this link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/sdk/overview/)
I got error 500.
I try to fix it with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58209929/importing-the-graph-kit-in-react-native-results-in-error-500) but it didn't worked

Comment: welcome to SO, Putting the stack trace for the error  might help to get a better solution

Comment: Are you behind a proxy ?

Comment: I use VPN. I tried without VPN too